# How can I create an empty file without a filename / path in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Once in a while I just want to write some things down. I don't want to include it (at the moment) in any package and I don't want to think about where to store it. I just want to write. (I saw [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-empty-files.html), but there I have to decide where to store it before I write anything)

In Sublime Text, I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. What do I do in PyCharm?

Comment: I think this can help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-empty-files.html

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Maybe I miss something - I just edited my answer with that link. It didn't help me.

Comment: You could use scratch files.

Comment: What are scratch files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Scratch files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/scratches.html#Scratches.xml) :

> Sometimes you may need to create temporary notes or draft up some code
>   outside of the project context. Instead of switching to a different
>   application for this purpose, you can use scratch files and scratch
>   buffers.

You can procced as follow:

> #### Create a scratch file
>
> 1. Do one of the following:
>
>    - Press `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Insert`.
>    - Press `Ctrl+Shift+A`, start typing `scratch file` and then pick the
>        corresponding action.
> 2. Select the language of the scratch file. Scratch files of the same
>      type are automatically numbered and added to the Scratches and
>      Consoles directory of the Project tool window .

Comment: What is "Insert"? - I tried "Enter", but it didn't work

Comment: It depends of your keybord, for me, it's next to `suppr`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key

Comment: Thank you! I never used that key  - on my German keyboard it is called "einfg" for "einfügen".